# как отследить изменение текста в input angular js?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Есть input, необходимо при его изменении что-то делать, например изменять значение переменной(знаю как), либо (это для меня сложное) изменять свойство `[checked]` для другого `<input type=checkbox>`.
Я пробовал писать что-то типа

`[(ngChange)]="Func()"`

но код не работает

`[ngChangeOptions]=""`

тоже не помогает, если можно использовать какие-то другие методы, например subscribe, хотелось бы получить пример.

Спасибо.

```
 <div class="input">
                    <label class="input__label"></label>
                    <input
                      [readonly]="!fields_to_show?.inputs?.sum?.editable"
                      [placeholder]="fields_to_show?.inputs?.sum?.range ? fields_to_show?.inputs?.sum?.range.min + ' - ' + fields_to_show?.inputs?.sum?.range.max : ''"
                      [formControlName]="fields_to_show?.inputs?.sum?.full_name"
                      [ngClass]="{
                        valid: form.controls[fields_to_show?.inputs?.sum?.full_name]?.valid && form.controls[fields_to_show?.inputs?.sum?.full_name]?.touched,
                        invalid: form.controls[fields_to_show?.inputs?.sum?.full_name]?.invalid && form.controls[fields_to_show?.inputs?.sum?.full_name]?.touched
                      }"
                      (focus)="sum_focus(form.controls[fields_to_show?.inputs?.sum?.full_name])"
                      (focusout)="sum_focus(form.controls[fields_to_show?.inputs?.sum?.full_name], true)"
                      class="input__field rub"
                      type="number"
                      required=""
                  maxlength="12">
              </div>
```

upd.
`(input)=` и `(change)=` работают, теперь следующий вопрос, `func()`, которая применяется к  `(input)=` или `(change)=` изменяет boolean переменную X.

Есть второй input checkbox, в нём есть `[change]='Число'`, число больше нуля.

Я изменяю `[change]='Число+X'`, но checkbox сбрасывается только один раз, как сделать так, чтобы он сбрасывался при каждом изменении первого input.

Comment: `(change)="Func()"` должно работать. Как вы определили, что он не работает?

Comment: конкретно `(change)="func()"` не работает, ну, например я попробовал вывести в `func()` `console.log(25)` ничего не выводит, строку не выводит, переменные тоже

Comment: **КАК** вы определяете, что она не работает? Ошибки в консоли? Или как?

Comment: `(change)="func()"` сработает в момент `blur` элемента. Если вам нужно, что бы функция вызывалась при каждом изменении значения, то используйте `(input)`.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko я вывожу  в func() в консоль переменные, они не выводятся -> функция не запускается

Comment: когда пишу [ngChange]="func()" выводит следующее: Can't bind to 'ngChange' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.

Comment: @IvanBurilichev, а зачем вы односторонне биндите свойство которое не существует? ))

Comment: @overthesanity а как его объявить? я просто не понимаю, почему у меня не работает ни (change) ни (input) ни ng-change а ngChange вообще выдаёт ошибки

Comment: @IvanBurilichev, я думаю вам быстрее было бы не тут вопрос задавать, а почитать документацию angular по байндингу событий :)

Comment: Потому что `ngChange` и `ng-change` не существует в `angular`. Существует только `(change)` или `(input)`, Вы попробовали  `(input)`?

Comment: (input) и (change) заработали, я что-то не так делал, уточню вопрос